# Permission denied on File.Copy using C# dotnet core CENTOS with samba mount

Tags: .net-core, centos, samba

When using File.Copy,

```
File.Copy(file.FullName, Path.Combine(config.DestinationDir, file.Name), true);
```

I encountered the following issue:

```
"ClassName": "System.UnauthorizedAccessException",
        "Message": "Access to the path is denied.",
        "Data": null,
        "InnerException": {
          "ClassName": "System.IO.IOException",
          "Message": "Operation not permitted",
          "Data": null,
          "InnerException": null,
          "HelpURL": null,
          "StackTraceString": null,
          "RemoteStackTraceString": null,
          "RemoteStackIndex": 0,
          "ExceptionMethod": null,
          "HResult": 1,
          "Source": null,
          "WatsonBuckets": null
        }
```

This looks a permission issue. However:

- I have the correct permission on both source and destination folder
- I can execute commands like mv/cp/touch on the destination folder without issue
- This issue appears only when the destination folder is a SAMBA mnt.
- I have no problem by using File.Read and File.Write (which .... should trigger the exception if it was linked to some basic permission issue)
- If I run the command with SUDO, no problem.

Here is the result of ls -ld on the destination folder:

```
drwxrwxr-x. 2 svc_smb_share grp_smb_share 0 24 jui 14:49 DestinationFolder
```

My user belongs to the grp_smb_share and therefore have the read/write/execute permission.

A note about my configuration:

- Server using Centos (centos-release-7-7.1908.0.el7.centos.x86_64)
- dotnet core (3.1.100)

Do you have any clue ?